# Index / Aggregate formula with Search

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sample data (1,2,3,4) on A2:D2 columns and on F1, I have (1,3), and on G1 (2,3,4).

I was suggested to use this formula

`=INDEX($A2:$D2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A2:$D2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT($A2:$D2,"000,"),F$1&",")),1))`

on F2, and G2 which is supposed to give the matching values on F2 and G2 respectively. Since both values (1,3) match, the result should be (1,3) on F2, and (2,3,4) on G2.

So basically this formula is supposed to work like index/match formula but instead of single values, it works on comma separated 2 or 3 values.

When I try to use the formula I keep getting `#NUM!` error. Can I get a little help to make this formula work, please?

Thanks.

*Note: I am open to alternative solutions, but if it requires VBA, it has to be with a user defined formula. Without UDF, it is not useful for me.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UDF should look like this

```
Option Explicit
Function MultFind(r As Range, s As String) As String

Dim c As Range
Dim result As String


For Each c In r
   If InStr("," & s & ",", "," & c & ",") <> 0 Then result = result & c & ","
Next c

If Len(result) > 0 Then result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

MultFind = result


End Function
```

Called as

```
=MultFind($A2:$D2,F1)
```

**Edit**

Here it is with optional parameter for delimiter:

```
Option Explicit
Function MultFind(r As Range, s As String, Optional delimiter As String = ",") As String

Dim c As Range
Dim result As String

' Check each cell in range against search string

For Each c In r
    If InStr(delimiter & s & delimiter, delimiter & c & delimiter) <> 0 Then result = result & c & delimiter
Next c

' Delimiter may be more than one character

If Len(result) > 0 Then result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delimiter))

MultFind = result

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. This works perfectly for single digit numbers. but when I enter  double digit numbers in F1 like (15,21), I get the following match (1,2,5).  Is it possible to change so it distinguishes single and double digit numbers?

Comment: Rookie error! Will update to account for multiple digits. I guess it should be made so that you can specify what delimiter you want to use and not just a comma, but will do that later.